# jQuery Mobile not styling appended elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

For some reason jQuery doesn't seem to style ui elements I add dynamically from JS like so:

```
<div id="menu">
    <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
    <div id="menu-buttons" data-role="controlgroup">
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $('#menu-buttons').append('<a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="star">Star button</a>')
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `$('#menu-buttons').trigger("create")`

Comment: from jqm 1.4 you have to add button classes yourself, so something like `ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-star ui-shadow` will do

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the jqm styling is done via js and just appending html isn't enough. If you manipulate or add a buttons via js, you should call the refresh method to update the visual styling.

```
$('#menu-buttons, #menu-buttons').button().button('refresh');
```

My selectors are just a guess. Acualy you should give it own id or class for better selecting.

Comment: Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on button prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, just forgot that it should be initialized with button() first. So correct is button().button('refresh'). Just updated the answer. But still keep an eye on the selectors - don't know which one would work. It should be only one of them.